# OpenSUSE VMware VM not taking space allocated?

Tags: opensuse, virtual-machine, disk-usage, vmware

I have an OpenSUSE VM running in VMware given to me as part of a project. It acts as a database container and the DB is hydrated by an outside script.

I started getting space warnings during the build process and build seems to be stalling so I tried to increase disk size from 20GB to 35GB.

Inside of My Computer in OpenSUSE, it's telling me there is only 18.6GiB total space.

I've restarted multiple times with no luck. Also, the new 35GB is pre-allocated.

I don't know if this will fix the build issue, but can someone help get the vm to recognize the full space allocated? Should at least help...

Extra info:

- OS: Linux 2.6.37.1-1.2-desktop x86_64
- System: openSUSE 11.4 (x86_64)
- KDE: 4.6.00 (4.6.0) "release 6"

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the additional disk space is not visible by the vm because it is not allocated to a partition.

The solution is to resize the partition of the vm.

A first step involves getting the unallocated space into the last partion, which can be done using parted. See https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/parted_31.html

The second step is to grow the filesystem of the partition to fill the new space. The way to do it depends on the format of the partition. Eg in case of ext4 you can find instructions at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ext4grow.html

Comment: Thanks. Well I ran `resize2fs /dev/sda2` and got...
`resize2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
The filesystem is already 4955648 blocks long. Nothing to do!`

Comment: What is output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda` ?

Comment: just upload it in pastebin or something like that.

Comment: Screenshot, haha http://prnt.sc/dh4hec

Comment: OK. My bad. I edited my answer. Hopefully it *should be* complete now :)

Comment: Awesome, getting somewhere. When I try to do the `rm 1` step in parted, I get "Error: Partition /dev/sda1 is being used. You must unmount it before you modify it with Parted." But when I exit parted and do `umount /dev/sda1`, I get "umount: /dev/sda1: not mounted" Also tried both with sudo, no luck. Thoughts?

Comment: I believe you need sda2 not sda1. And of course you need it to be unused (ie not boot from it but from an installation media or something) in order to resize it.

Comment: Hmm... I figured out how to mount a gparted ISO to the vm, then change the boot order in the BIOS, reboot to gparted, then just used its GUI. But I wouldn't have found my way there without your help!